# Refreshing a view in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, rcp

I have a view(A) in which, on a button click in some other view(B) I get some content here.

My problem is if I click on the same button of view(B) again, the contents of view(A) are getting appended to the previous contents of it.

I mean, the previous contents should be erased and new contents should be added.

But I am getting both old contents and new contents appended to it.

How to refresh the view so that the old contents will get erased.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: Are these both your views? Show us the code you use to do this.